# Why do I have to enter length of array while using "typeid"?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, typeid

I am learning c++11, and while I want to test `typeid` syntax , I don't understand that **why do I have to enter length of array to recognize it ?**

For example  :

```
 char name[9];
 if (typeid(name) == typeid(char []) // without length 
     cout<<"Okay"<<endl;             // not print
```

---

```
 char name[9];
 if (typeid(name) == typeid(char [9]) // with length 
     cout<<"Okay"<<endl;              // okay
```

But if I don't write **length** `9` it does not work and I have to enter **length**`9`. well, **Why?**

Therefore :

```
if (typeid(name) == typeid(char))       // only char wrong | ok | logical 
if (typeid(name) == typeid(char *))     // by * wrong      | ok | logical
if (typeid(name) == typeid(char []))    // onle [] wrong   | don't understand 
if (typeid(name) == typeid(char [9]))   // okay            | but why ?
```

---

I expect `typeid(char[])` to work. In fact what is length of array for?

Comment: An array without a length is not an array.

Comment: @tuple_cat `char[]` is an array type, so I'm not sure what you mean by that comment

Comment: Don't let `T[]` notation in function parameters fool you - in function declarations `T[]` (and `T[9]` as well) is parsed *exactly* as if it was `T*`, and that's the reason why you can pass arrays of any size to functions (arrays decay to pointers to the first element); this does not mean that `T[]` is a complete type or that `T[]`, `T[1]` and `T[2]` are the same type.

Comment: (also, variable definitions such as `int foo[] = {1, 2, 3};` are just a shorthand for `int foo[3] = {1, 2, 3};`; again, `int[]` is not a complete type, you cannot have variables of type `int[]`)

Comment: @M.M: uhm, where is it specified exactly? I'm referring to C++11 §8.3.5 ¶5 *After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of `T`” or “function returning `T`” is adjusted to be “pointer to `T`” or “pointer to function returning `T`,” respectively.*; I see no mention to incomplete types here.

Comment: @MatteoItalia you're right. Comment retracted. They differ in C but not in C++. (in C, `T[]` is illegal for incomplete type)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Sure you can have variables of type `int[]`: `extern int a[];` (But you cannot *define* a variable of such type.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`char[2]` is something else than `char[3]`. They are totally separated types. The number of element is not just a parameter. It is part of the type itself.

You can consider the number of element as follow:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
class array{
public:
    T[N] data;
}
```

if you want to use this class,you should write:

```
array<int,6> foo;
array<int,7> bar;
```

At compile time array type will be converted to something like this:

```
array_int_6 foo;
array_int_7 bar;
```

It is obvious that `array_int_6 != array_int_7`. Thus leads to : `typeid(foo) != typeid(bar)` and `typeid(array<int,6>) != typeid(array<int,7>)`

Answer (score 6):

The size of an array is part of its type.  A `char[7]` is not the same thing as a `char[8]`.  We can demonstrate that with

```
void foo(char (&arr)[6]) {}
```

Now with that function we could only pass an array of the type `char[6]`.  looking at this [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9caa863b5bda6494) you can see the compiler will complain for arrays that do not match the size specified in the function.